# Cannot start code review on Helix Swarm using P4V

Tags: perforce, p4v, swarm

When I request a swarm review through P4V on my machine I get the message `"Review could not be created. Unauthorized".`

Then when I try to update a swarm review it says `Review ID not found`.
Also, when I go to my pending change lists the `Review ID` field remains empty even if a swarm review is open for the change list.

I'm using an XPS running windows 11 but when I use a virtual machine running Windows 11 P4V seems to work fine, and I get none of the issue listed above. It seems that my account is permitted to create a swarm review but for some reason P4V won't allow it on my environment.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it already. If anyone might have any ideas/insight it would be greatly appreciated!

** Fixed **
I contacted their support team and they released an update soon after that fixed my issue.

Thank you

Comment: What version is p4v? What version is your swarm?

Answer (score 0):

Same situation. I tried the following method and it works.
Menu bar - connection - reconnected to swarm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, though for me things like "Show changeset in Swarm" worked fine. Also, validating the Swarm installation by using the #review keyword in the changeset description (as mentioned here https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v21.1/swarm/Content/Swarm/setup.validate_install.html#Validate_your_Swarm_installation) worked fine for me as well.

What I did:

- in the P4V client: Edit -> Preferences -> Connections -> Enable "Use IP-specific tickets when logging in"
- restart P4V client
  -> it started working (no idea why)

Why did I do that?
I came across their instructions here: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4vs/Content/P4VS/other.swarm.html

There it says "If you get authorization errors, ensure that the Use IP-specific tickets when logging in is disabled." For me, that setting was already disabled, but I wanted to see what happened if I enable it. So I enabled it, it started working. Then I disabled it again, and at the moment it still working.